# Multi Level mappings in Parent/Child hierarchy in D3 Possible?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've a flat file which is of format

```
"id":1,"depends_on":2
"id":1,"depends_on":4
"id":1,"depends_on":5
"id":2,"depends_on":3
"id":4,"depends_on":5
```

Normally if I don't have

```
"id":1,"depends_on":5
```

I can plot the D3 Layout as follows

[image: without multi level mappings]

When I include `"id":1,"depends_on":5`

Graph that's being plot will be

[image: with multi level mappings]

Ideally I should have a line between 1 & 5 too, along with other mappings.

1)**How can I achieve this?**

2)**How should the data-structure should be?** 
Does it really need to have duplicate entries (objects) in various parts of main data-structure ( to obtain in the format D3 needed (parent,children[])

Using d3.layout.force produces

[image: Force Layout]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292), which uses [`d3.layout.force()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout).

A force layout's data structure involves 2 arrays:

an array of nodes

```
[{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}]`
```

and array of links

```
[
  { source: {id: 1}, target: {id: 2} },
  { source: {id: 1}, target: {id: 3} }, 
  { source: {id: 2}, target: {id: 4} }
]
```

The objects used in the nodes array and links array should be the same objects. I.e, in the example above, `nodes[0] == links.source[0]` should be true.

Comment: Aware of this, but this seems more cluttered.I'm looking for more of a cluster layout, than force layout. Is it possible to accommodate in the same?

NOTE: Updated with image.